# WPS Office - Change Spreadsheets Default Fill Background Color

Tags: wps-office

I installed WPS Office for the first time.  It is amazing, so much so that I wonder if there is some hidden adware that I can't remove (e.g., what is Docer).

That said, my issue is that the background on WPS Spreadsheets for all sheets is this weird brown color.  I've tried changing the `Page Layout` > `Themes` and `Colors`.  I've also tried to `Format Cells`.  But there does not appear (or I can't find) a way to change the default background color. Is there a way?

Here is what it looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an addendum to Roel Brook's answer, I found that you can actually change this setting in the binary file. To do this open terminal and enter

```
sudo $EDITOR `where et`
```

Then look for:

```
${gInstallPath}/office6/${gApp} -style gtk+ ${gOptExt} ${gOpt} "$@"
```

and change it to:

```
${gInstallPath}/office6/${gApp} -style motif ${gOptExt} ${gOpt} "$@"
```

Then save and close. Now the changes will be persistent.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Temkin.  I attempted to edit the binary file, but I had no `et` file in `/bin`.  Instead, it was at `/usr/bin/et`.  Also, and more importantly, it doesn't have the line you mention.  There is no `-style gtk+` anywhere in the file.  The closest line I have is: `else ${gInstallPath}/office6/${gApp} ${gOptExt} ${gOpt} "$@" `.  Am I in the wrong directory?

Comment: I missed the 5 minute edit time restriction.  Here is what I meant to add:   Despite the different directory, I added `-style motif` in the same place you had it.  And it worked!!!  I'm going to go through a few restarts to see if it sticks.  If so, I'll mark it solved and thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

> GTK theme have to be set with environment variable and parameter
>
> env GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc ./et -style gtk+
>
> > Can you show a way to input this parameter to the application to be persistent? >>I'm using KDE Neon 5.14 User Edition (Based Ubuntu 18.04)
> >
> > Thanks a Lot man

--UPDATE--

Knowing about this tip that intika said, a precious one by the way, I searched a little more to How to make this line as permanent. So, its very simple.

Right Click  > Edit Application > Application tab >  Run or Command box-form and add "Exec="on  begining.

For exemple:

```
Exec=env GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc /usr/bin/et -style gtk+
```

This solved my problem. Take care to do not put this command to run in a terminal on advanced settings, or It will open terminal together (unless you want it)

Comment: This is a great, useful answer and it's valuable that you point out the potential problems one could have. One minor improvement could be to make it less of a log of what you did and more a description of what should be done, as that'd be more readable for future readers. (For example, you could change the second update to something like "Be careful not to enable the option to run in a terminal (...), as that causes a terminal to be opened at the same time as the spreadsheet(...)".)

Comment: @aplaice . Thank you, I read about to write a good answer, but in the end, i dont get it very well.   I will edit this post to make more readable to future reader. Thanks a lot for the tip.

Comment: If you installed WPS through snap... edit `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/wps-office_et.desktop` and add it like: `Exec=env GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/wps-office_et.desktop /snap/bin/wps-office.et -style gtk+ %U`

Answer (score 2):

As with most QT applications, WPS accepts "-style".

For example:
et -style motif

This will ignore the current desktop theme, and run WPS with that specific QT theme.

Comment: Thanks @Roel Brook, but that solution actually doesn't work other than when launching through the terminal.  If you put the `et -style motif` in the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`, it only works when you launch from that directory.  Else (e.g., if you open a .xlsx file in another location or a blank document), it keeps the brown background.

Comment: works for me if I edit the launcher properties in Linux Mint Cinnamon 18 as follows:  command: /usr/bin/et  -style motif

Answer (score 2):

GTK theme have to be set with environment variable and parameter

```
env GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc ./et -style gtk+
```

Comment: I get gtk+ not a valid file

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is caused by an interaction with the Arc Dark theme (it does not occur with Arc or Arc Darker).  I [posted an issue](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme/issues/748) on Horst's GitHub page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the solution above given by Dan (which seems to be the right one as it is referenced in every forum I came across) wasn't working for me. But I found another fix which DOES work, although not permanently.

I am using a KDE neon build, and the solution below worked for me:

```
WPS_NO_KDE_NATIVE_DIALOG=1 et -style gtk+
```

This is for spreadsheets. For writer and presentation, substitute "et" with "wps" and "wpp" respectively.

Solution attributed to user "raddison" on KDE Forum, under the "[WPS Office not working](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=140892&start=45)" topic.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem using flatpak version:

```
flatpak install com.wps.Office
```

Then you need to edit Qt config file:

```
nano ~/.var/app/com.wps.Office/config/Trolltech.conf
```

Add this lines:

```
[Qt]
style=Plastique
```

You could also use other Qt styles inclueded in the default installation:
`CDE`, `Cleanlooks`, `GTK`, `Motif`, `Plastique`, `Windows`